# Заполнение массива числами

Tags: php

Требуется заполнять массив числами 0 и 1 в случайном порядке, но чтобы в конечном итоге соотношение этих чисел было примерно такое: 0(60/40)1.
Кол-во чисел должно быть разным.
Может быть кто-то писал такое и может поделиться кодом? Или же можете натолкнуть на путь истинный в решении данного вопроса?

Comment: сгенерите случайное число от 0 до 20. прибавьте к нему 50. получите число N, пройдите по массиву, добавьте N-нулей и 100-N единиц. вызовите `array_shuffle`

Comment: можно не ходить по массиву, а создать один длиной N с нулями, и второй на 100-N с единицами. затем объединить и перемешать

Comment: @teran Спасибо) Совсем забыл про array_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

перенесу комментарии в ответ:

> сгенерите случайное число от 0 до 20. прибавьте к нему 50. получите число N, пройдите по массиву, добавьте N-нулей и 100-N единиц. вызовите `shuffle`

```
$r = rand(50,70); //rand(0,20) + 50;
$result = [];
$idx = 0;
while($idx++ < 100){
    $result[] = (int)($idx > $r);
};
shuffle($result);
print_r($result);
```

> можно не ходить по массиву, а создать один длиной N с нулями, и второй на 100-N с единицами. затем объединить и перемешать

```
$a = array_fill(0, $r, 1);
$b = array_fill(0, 100-$r, 0);
$result = array_merge($a, $b);
```